# Как передать нужные значения в функцию? (NSDateComponents)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Есть код, который считает сколько прошло времени. Возвращать она должна время умноженное на число.

Так как время это не одно число (например, прошло 8 часов 23 минуты), я разделил минуты на 100 и прибавил их к часам (8 + 23/100 = 8.23), сохранив это в одну переменную. При делении всегда получается 0, т.к число Int, конвертировать в Double не получается.

Не могу решить две проблемы. Как правильно написать деление минут на 100?
В функцию нужно передать 4 значения: начальное время (часы, минуты) и конечное (часы, минуты). Возможно код неправильный. Как передать значения?

PS Работаю с `NSDateComponents` первый раз.

```
func wTime (firstTime: (Int, Int), secondTime: (Int, Int)) -> (Double) {

    let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    //задаем первую дату
    var firstTime = NSDateComponents()
    firstTime.hour = 0
    firstTime.minute = 0

    var firstDate = userCalendar.dateFromComponents(firstTime)!

    //задаем вторую дату
    var secondTime = NSDateComponents()
    secondTime.hour = 0 
    secondTime.minute = 0

    var secondDate = userCalendar.dateFromComponents(secondTime)!

    let hourMinute: NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour,
                                      .Minute]

    //находим разницу между первой и второй датами
    let difference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(
        hourMinute,
        fromDate: firstDate,
        toDate: secondDate,
        options: [])


    var mon = Double (difference.hour + difference.minute/100)
    var monTime = Double (money * 150)

    return monTime
}

//попытка передать значения

var firsTime = (hour: 7, minute: 30)
var secoTime = (hour: 16, minute: 00)
wTime(firsTime, secondTime: secoTime) // => 0
```

Comment: не совсем понятно, что именно вы делаете. время по моему вам лучше всего хранить в формате NSDate - тогда отняв конечное время от начального вы получите милисекунды, а их уже перевести в часы/минуты не сложно.

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Мне нужен был код для нахождения времени, сколько прошло часов от и до. На одном форуме подсказали этот код. Потому что я пока не могу додуматься как это реализовать. В Playground'е все работало. Для дальнейшего применения решил написать функцию на основе этого кода. В итоге работает, только не так как надо. Если изменить нулевые значения на любые другие,то выдаст нужный результат, но без минут. Минуты делятся на 100 и в результате ноль.

Comment: ну если проблема в делении на 100 то `var mon = Double(difference.hour) + Double(difference.minute)/100`

Comment: С делением все работает)))спасибо большое. А значения как передать? В дальнейшем буду через TextField передавать значения first.hour/minute и second.hour/minute.

Comment: я все еще не понимаю, что вы хотите сделать. и минуты делить на 100 по моему не лучшая идея (их все таки 60)

Comment: Делю потому что если сложить 8 часов и 30 минут,то получится 38. Если поделить 30 на 100, то тогда будет примерно так 8+0.3 =8.3.

Comment: а если 8 часов умножить на 60 и прибавить минуты?

Comment: А смысл? Если так проще. Код работает как надо теперь, но вот передать значения не получается.

Comment: можете указать на место в коде, где не получается передать. может так мне понятнее будет

Comment: все, понял. сейчас попробую

Comment: Все что в коде равно изначально нулю. Например first.hour и first.minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Черт ногу сломит в ваших переменных. Что то типа такого попробуйте

```
func wTime (firstTime: (Int, Int), secondTime: (Int, Int)) -> (Double) {

    let userCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    //задаем первую дату
    var firstTimeCom = NSDateComponents()
    firstTimeCom.hour = firstTime.0
    firstTimeCom.minute = firstTime.1

    var firstDate = userCalendar.dateFromComponents(firstTimeCom)!

    //задаем вторую дату
    var secondTimeCom = NSDateComponents()
    secondTimeCom.hour = secondTime.0
    secondTimeCom.minute = secondTime.1

    var secondDate = userCalendar.dateFromComponents(secondTimeCom)!

    let hourMinute: NSCalendarUnit = [.Hour,
        .Minute]

    //находим разницу между первой и второй датами
    let difference = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(
        hourMinute,
        fromDate: firstDate,
        toDate: secondDate,
        options: [])


    var mon = Double(difference.hour) + Double(difference.minute)/100
    var monTime = Double (money * 150)

    return monTime
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все работает. За код извините, он не мой.

Comment: и все таки не храните минуты в дробной части. я так понимаю, у вас оплата считается по времени. Не очень приятно отработать пол часа, а денег получить за 0.3 :)

Comment: переводите время в минуты. отличный вариант: (часы*60+минуты)*(оплата-за-час/60)

Comment: Работает:). Исправлю код. Спасибо.